# Top attached toasts in R-Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

According to the `Fomantic UI`- documentation, the following script produces a top attached `toast`:

```
$.toast({
  position: 'top attached',
  title: 'Watch out!',
  message: `I am a top attached toast`
});
```

In the `R` wrapper `shiny.semantic`, the `showNotification` function doesn't obey the `top attached` command, but it does obey the positional arguments in general, as seen in the minimal working example (MWE) provided below.

```
# library
library(shiny)
library(shiny.semantic)

# application

if (interactive()) {
  
  shiny::shinyApp(
    
    ui = semanticPage(
      title = 'Title',
      actionButton(
        inputId = 'show',
        label = 'Click me!'
      ),
      actionButton(
        inputId = 'bottom_left',
        label = 'Bottom left!'
      ),
      actionButton(
        inputId = 'top_attached',
        label = 'Top attached!'
      )
    ),
    
    server = function(input,output) {
      
      observeEvent(
        input$bottom_left,
        {
          showNotification(
            ui = 'Where am I?',
            type = 'default',
            position = 'bottom left'
          )
        }
      )
      
      observeEvent(
        input$top_attached,
        {
          showNotification(
            ui = 'Where am I?',
            type = 'default',
            position = 'top attached'
          )
        }
      )
      
      observeEvent(
        input$show,
        {
          toast(
            title = 'See me!',
            message = 'Where am I?',
            toast_tags = tags$script(
              "($.toast({position: 'top attached'}))"
            )
          )
        }
      )
      
    }
    
  )
  
}
```

How do I make the `showNotification` or `toast` function obey the `top attached` command using base `R` and `shiny.semantic`?

Comment: I don't know. Just a note: are you aware of the **shinyToastify** package?

Comment: I am not - I will definetly look into it, if I dont find an answer. I am trying to keep Application depencies to a minimum!

Answer (score 1):

Although not documented, `toast_tags` takes a named vector or list. So your call to `toast()` should be:

```
toast(
  title = 'See me!',
  message = 'Where am I?',
  toast_tags = list(position = 'top attached')
)
```

This works for me in your MWE (as does `toast_tags = c(position = 'top attached')`)